# PHP DOMDocument error handling

Tags: php, xml, exception, dom, error-handling

In my application I am loading xml from url in order to parse it.
But sometimes this url may not be valid. In this case I need to handle errors.
I have the following code:

```
$xdoc = new DOMDocument();
try{
  $xdoc->load($url); // This line causes Warning: DOMDocument::load(...)
                     // [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: 
                     // HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in ...
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $xdoc = null;
}

if($xdoc == null){
  // Handle
} else {
  // Proceed
}
```

I know I probably doing it wrong, but what's a correct way to handle this kind of exceptions? I don't want to see error messages on my page.

The manual for DOMDocument::load() says:

> If an empty string is passed as the
>   filename  or an empty file is named, a
>   warning will be generated. This
>   warning is not generated by libxml and
>   cannot be handled using libxml's error
>   handling functions.

But there is no information on how to handle it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From what I can gather from the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php), handling warnings issued by this method is tricky because they are not generated by the libxml extension and thus cannot be handled by `libxml_get_last_error()`. You could either use the error suppression operator and check the return value for `false`...

```
if (@$xdoc->load($url) === false)
    // ...handle it
```

...or register [an error handler which throws an exception on error](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php):

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
```

and then catch it.

Comment: You can also use libxml_use_internal_errors(false) to suppress the error and check the data for errors

Comment: This worked perfect to check if there is no internet connection:
if (@$xdoc->load($url) === false)

Answer (score 8):

```
set_error_handler(function($number, $error){
    if (preg_match('/^DOMDocument::loadXML\(\): (.+)$/', $error, $m) === 1) {
        throw new Exception($m[1]);
    }
});

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($xmlData);

restore_error_handler();
```

That works for me in PHP 5.3. But if you're not using `loadXML`, you might need to do some modifications.

Comment: I am using loadXML, but still doesn't help... :(

Comment: @Znarkus I believe the current solution contains a small bug.  In order for this code to have no side effects, the custom error handler must be popped off the stack *regardless* of whether `loadXML()` completed without errors.  Currently, if `loadXML()` emits an error that's intercepted by the custom error handler, `restore_error_handler();` will never be invoked.  The custom error handler will remain in effect -- which we almost certainly don't want.  To fix this, I'd suggest adding a call to `restore_error_handler();` inside the closure's `if` statement, right before throwing the exception.

Answer (score 5):

To disable throwing errors:

```
$internal_errors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
// etc...

libxml_use_internal_errors($internal_errors);
```

Comment: Read the manual. This warning is not generated by libxml and cannot be handled using libxml's error handling functions.

Comment: Works perfectly, when used with `libxml_get_last_error()`.

Answer (score 1):

From php.net

> If an empty string is passed as the
>   filename  or an empty file is named, a
>   warning will be generated. This
>   warning is not generated by libxml and
>   cannot be handled using libxml's error
>   handling functions.

In your production environment you shouldn't have errors displayed to the user. They don't need to see them so taking this into account you can use...

```
$xdoc = new DOMDocument();
if ( $xdoc->load($url) ) {
    // valid
}
else {
    // invalid
}
```

Comment: Because `load` can sometimes emit warnings, this solution would only work if you disable error reporting completely, which is a bad practice. If you merely hide the error from the users, then you'd not end up in the `// invalid` block and therefore would not handle the error as you intended. The correct approach is using `set_error_handler`.

Answer (score 0):

For me , following did the trick

```
$feed = new DOMDocument();  
$res= @$feed->load('http://www.astrology.com/horoscopes/daily-extended.rss');
if($res==1){
           //do sth
          }
```