# new DomDocument() do not work with getElementsByTagName('section');

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, domdocument

I would like to have different outputs if the file is called by Ajax or not.
For that I have this code witch works fine:

```
/* AJAX check  */
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $content = get_content();
    die($content);
}
```

my function for filtering the contend is this:

```
function get_content(){
    //$file = file_get_contents('index.html'); //works better but i get only errors
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); //or $file
    $section= $dom->getElementsByTagName('section');
    return $section->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

my output is always empty. 
Whats wrong here?

!!!I'am not looking for DOMDocument error handling!!!!

What I do for now is:

```
/* decide what the content should be up here .... */

/* AJAX check  */
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    /* if ajax,  show only content of the section tag */
    $file = file_get_contents($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
    $section = preg_replace("/.*<section[^>]*>|<\/section>.*/si", "", $file);
    die($section);
}

/* not ajax, show page.... */
```

and it seems to work. I do not know it is the best solution because somewhere in this forum I read that its better to realise that with DomDocument().
Any suggestions are welcome?

Here is the html-file:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- Determine browser JS free -->
<!-- HTML5 Mobile Boilerplate -->
<!--[if IEMobile 7]><html class="no-js iem7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->

<!-- HTML5 Boilerplate -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 7)&!(IEMobile)]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 8)&!(IEMobile)]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->


<head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>title</title>


            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/base/favicon.html" />
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="img/base/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.html" />
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="img/base/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.html" />
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="img/base/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.html" />
            <script src="/js/libs/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
            <!--[if (IE 7)]>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fallback/icons-ie7.css">
            <![endif]-->

            </head>

    <body >


        <section role="main">

    <header class="hero-banner">
        <img class="resize" src="/img/base/spacer-hero.png" rel="/img/designers/banners/cloe-banner3.jpg" alt="Cloe" />
        <noscript><img src="/img/designers/banners/cloe-banner3.jpg" alt="Cloe" /></noscript>
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Claudia</h1>
            <h2 class="text-hl">Designerin</h2>
        </hgroup>
    </header>


        </section>



        <footer role="contentinfo">


            <p><small>&copy;2013 joe</small></p>
            <p><small>Our website uses delicious cookies to improve your experience. We'll assume you're ok with that.</small></p>


        </footer>


        <!-- jQuery from Google's CDN with local fallback -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/libs/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script src="/js/libs/wfl.js"></script>

        <!-- Initialises scripts from plugins.js and helper.js -->
        <script src="/js/script.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Goggles -->


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to show the HTML file contents.

Comment: Don't you know the file contents ? If not why would you try to get section tags ?

Comment: you wont that i post the complete html-file?

Comment: No i don't want anymore...

Comment: My question do not goes to the error-handling.
The problem I have is that the result is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the errors of by setting internal errors to true:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;

$before = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors($before);
```

You then won't have the errors logged any longer. In your case most likely you've got display errors enabled which might be okay for development, but on your production server, please switch to error logging otherwise your website would reveal too much data to the outside.

See as well:

- [PHP DOMDocument error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759069/367456)