# DOMDocument load throws a warning

Tags: php

Warning:DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

```
<?php 

if($xmlDoc->load($url)){
    ...
}
else{
    die("the link is not an rss");
}
```

I tried put 
    $xmlDoc->load($url)

in a try block and tried

```
if (@$xdoc->load($url) === false)
```

from : [PHP DOMDocument error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759069/php-domdocument-error-handling)

but the warning still shows. how do I avoid this warning?

Comment: Do you have `allow_url_fopen` set to `On` in your `php.ini`

Comment: it should get an rss address from a user so I'm trying to check if it's a feed or not.

Comment: RiggsFolly where should this file be? i'm using PMA (i'm new to all this)

Comment: and can I only disable this warning? i'm still running checks on this site

Comment: I dont know what PMA is unless you mean phpMyAdmin and if thats what PMA is then what has that got to do with this error.

Comment: I though it's got something to do with the location of php.ini

Comment: I need to make it clear. it work fine for a good link. I need it to work even if the link is not good( not an rss), the site is getting a link to rss from a user(this is the check to see if the link given is good or not)